# How to set a variable value to be unchanged in an else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider this simple dropdown menu case: value of `arg` originally was `['a', 'b', 'c']`, once option orange is selected, `arg` is set to `['a', 'b']` and will not change back, unless redefine `arg`. I'd like to reset `arg` to its state prior to select the dropdown menu option on click of options other than orange.

My problem is, in my real code, before the option was selected, `arg` was defined by a complex logic thus impossible to reset by explicitly re-write all logic inside the `else` condition. Is there a way to do `else { // reset arg to its state before dropdown }`?

```js
let arg = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

$('#dropdown').change(function () {
  if ($('#dropdown').val() === 'orange') {
    arg = ['a', 'b'];
    console.log(arg);
  }
  else {
    // can I reset value of arg to ['a', 'b', 'c'] without explicitly doing arg=['a', 'b', 'c']?
    // something like arg.reset()
    console.log(arg);
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='dropdown'>
  <option value='apple'>apple</option>
  <option value='orange'>orange</option>
  <option value='pear'>pear</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You could put the "complex logic" which gets `arg` into a function, and then call the function again when you want to reset arg (you can change the function's behaviour by providing different arguments)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sounds a bit cumbersome to store in 2 variables and copy it?

Comment: True. @NickParsons approach is far better, it just depends how performat your calculation is

Answer (score 0):

You can store the array (and its deviations) as data attributes of the options:

```js
// Prepare...
let arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
$('#dropdown option').data("choices", arr)
   .filter('[value="orange"]').data("choices", ["a", "b"]);

$('#dropdown').change(function () {
    arr = $(":selected", this).data("choices"); // just grab
    console.log(arr);
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='dropdown'>
  <option value='apple'>apple</option>
  <option value='orange'>orange</option>
  <option value='pear'>pear</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper variable, e.g. `argOriginal`, to store the original list:

```js
let arg = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let argOriginal = arg;

$('#dropdown').change(function () {
  if ($('#dropdown').val() === 'orange') {
    arg = ['a', 'b'];
    console.log(arg);
  }
  else {
    arg = argOriginal;
    console.log(arg);
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='dropdown'>
  <option value='apple'>apple</option>
  <option value='orange'>orange</option>
  <option value='pear'>pear</option>
</select>
```